# How to have a generic out-parameter without any type restrictions

Tags: c#, generics, out, restrictions

The problem is this:
I want a generic function that has an out-parameter of the generic type.
Restrict the generic type to ref-type and there is no problem ofcourse.
But I wanted a totally unrestricted generic type! No new() or class/struct-restrictions!

```
public class A
{ }

public class B<T> : A
{
  public T t;
  public B(T i)
  {
    this.t = t;
  }
}

public static class S
{
  public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
  {
    C<T> c = a as C<T>;
    if(c != null)
    {
      t = c.t;
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
}

class Run
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    C<SomeType> c = new C<SomeType>(new SomeType(...));

    SomeType thing;
    S.Test<SomeType>(c,thing);
  }
}
```

The above code illustrates what I *want* to do. I want to set the out parameter, but only under a similar condition as the one depicted. In the false-case of `Test(...)` I'm totally uninterested in the value of `out t`. But the above is ofcourse not working code.
The problem above is that an `out` parameter *must* be initialized. But maybe initialization is sometimes expensive (depends on type of `T`) and I don't want to initialize a dummy class instance just to make the compiler stop complaining. So the question then becomes: How do you initialize an unknown type (and making sure it is initialized to null if it's a class)??

Well in theory you should be able to write something like

```
public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
{
  //...
  else
  {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
    {
      t = (T)0; //Can't cast from int to T error (Yeah, this is a little tricky...)
      //OR:
      t = new T(); //No-no, doesn't have the new()-restriction on T (But we know it's a value type... life sucks)
    }
    else
      t = null; //Error: Can't set to null! T could be valueType! (No it CAN'T... again life sucks)
    return false;
  }
}
```

But alas it's not so simple. The first problem is when T is value-type, we should be able to create it but compiler wont let us. The second problem is similar: "It could be a value-type!" - no, I just made sure it wasn't. It *should* work but it doesn't. Very annoying.

Ok. So we start to go creative... after all, there is this nice class called Object, and it has a special relation to all things C#'ish.

```
public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
{
  //...
  else
  {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
    {
      t = (T)(object)0; //Works ONLY if T is valuetype: int, otherwise you get a "must be less than infinity"-error.
    }
    else
    {
      t = (T)(object)null; //Null ref exception in the cast...
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This *compiles* atleast. But it's still rubbish. Runtime-error galore.
The problem with the value-type is that the object-type remembers what type it *really* is and when trying to cast to something else... strange things happen (infinity? Really??)
Well this damn well *should* be doable! So lets be *more* creative!

```
public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
{
  //...
  else
  {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
    {
      //... still rubbish here
    }
    else
    {
      object o = null;
      t = (T)o; //Tricked you stupid compiler!
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

That's right! It looks a stupid insignificant change... But this compiles - and for non-value-types this runs *and* gives exactly the result we want! If T is a ref-type it gets initilized to null.
Still the problem with value-types. Somewhat reluctantly creativity turns it attention to Reflection. After some random digging around on reflection-stuff, looking for something worth trying out (and no! you cant get the constructor for a value-type, it returns null) I stumbled across a small note on msdn:

> "To create an instance of a value type that has no instance
>   constructors, use the CreateInstance method."

Enter `CreateInstance<T>()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx.

> "The CreateInstance generic method is used by compilers to implement
>   the instantiation of types specified by type parameters."

Now we're getting somewhere! Sure it does say

> "In general, there is no use for the CreateInstance in application
>   code, because the type must be known at compile time. If the type is
>   known at compile time, normal instantiation syntax can be used (new
>   operator in C#, New in Visual Basic, gcnew in C++)."

But hey - we are not quite doing general stuff, we are in creative-mode, and the compiler is grumpy towards us. Totally justifies giving it a try.

```
public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
{
  //...
  else
  {
    if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
    {
      t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); //Probably not your everyday code...
    }
    else
    {
      object o = null;
      t = (T)o;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

AND BAM! That was it! It totally works *soo* good!
Below is some code thats been tested and run in both VS2010SP1 and MonoDevelop (with Unity3.4)

using System;

```
namespace GenericUnrestrictedOutParam
{
    class Program
    {
        class TestClass
        {
            public int i;
        }

        struct TestStruct
        {
            int i;
            TestClass thing;
        };

        public static void NullWorkaround<T>(out T anything)
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                anything = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                object o = null;
                anything = (T)o;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            float f;
            string s;
            TestStruct ts;
            TestClass c;

            NullWorkaround<int>(out i);
            NullWorkaround<float>(out f);
            NullWorkaround<string>(out s);
            NullWorkaround<TestStruct>(out ts);
            NullWorkaround<TestClass>(out c);
        } //Breakpoint here for value-checking
    }
}
```

And the glorious "output" (from locals-panel @ breakpoint):

```
        args    {string[0]} string[]
        i   0   int
        f   0.0 float
        s   null    string
-       ts  {GenericUnrestrictedOutParam.Program.TestStruct}    GenericUnrestrictedOutParam.Program.TestStruct
          i 0   int
          thing null    GenericUnrestrictedOutParam.Program.TestClass
        c   null    GenericUnrestrictedOutParam.Program.TestClass
```

Even the struct with a value and a class-type in it is beautifully handled: value type is 0, class instance is null.
**Mission accomplished!**

Comment: Just in case anyone was to suggest I use a ref instead of out: No because then I have to initialize *before* I pass it in to Test(). Totally defeats the whole idea.

Comment: TL;DR after half way through.  It looks like you finished by solving your own problem.  While it is fine to ask a question and also post an answer, please post your answer as an answer, not in the question.  This can work even if it isn't a great answer, and you're looking for other answers.  Or it can work if you slam dunked it - we aren't picky :)

Comment: Your code will break for any `struct` that you cannot assign `0` - you need `default(T)`

Comment: Sorry about that... Well anyway there is a real answer. I was apparently just making things hard for myself! ^^ 
Just for academic interest. Would you mind posting an example of when it breaks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your workaround seems unnecessary - you just need `default(T)` which works for both reference and value types:

```
public static bool Test<T>(ref A a, out T t)
{
  t = default(T);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, haha, I knew it should be doable... sometimes you forget the simplest things ^^